# Finding the file that's modified when you run a terminal command?

Tags: terminal

I want to know what file is modified when I run a terminal command like:

```
 osascript -e "set Volume 0.5"
```

Is there a way to do this? I'm thinking maybe a command that looks for recently modified files in setting directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you can use ‘opensnoop’ which will list files being accessed in realtime. You'll need to [disable SIP](https://georgegarside.com/blog/macos/package-incompatible-installer/) to use this command.

```
sudo opensnoop
```

To use opensnoop on a specific process such as osascript, use

```
sudo opensnoop -n osascript
```

For that specific command, no file is modified. It's setting the current volume, that's all.